# Horizontal menu background not showing up in IE 7,8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, menu

The site is appearing fine in Mozilla, Chrome, and IE6. But IE7 onwards, the menu background image was not appearing at all.
In the file moo.menu.css, I made the following changes in li:

```
.ry-cssmnu ul li {
margin: 0; /* all list items */
padding: 0;
float: left;
display: block;
background: url(../images/mainnav-bg.gif) repeat-x center top blue;/*added this line*/
cursor: pointer;}
```

After this, the background repeat is appearing only where the menu text is present.
http://bit.ly/ie8issue
The site is at: www.agmrcet.com/cons
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a height to that container. Your floating list items are not giving their parent container height because `float` removes them from the document flow. Your `<ul>` has a current height of nothing, and the background image won't remedy that.

```
#mainnav { height:44px; ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would change the CSS **background** property according to the CSS syntax:

```
background: blue url(../images/mainnav-bg.gif) repeat-x center top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with your

```
<div class="clearfix" id="mainnav">
```

tag. Have you tried adding a pink border or something (to debug it) to the mainnav element and then setting a fixed width on it to make sure it goes the full width?

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for the help. Its fixed in IE8. But IE7 still shows the same page. Moreover the hyperlinks are not working in firefox and chrome. Thank you once again to all of you for helping in such a short time.

Comment: Dawson is right below. You need to add height to the element as well. Adding the border as I suggested should make it clear where these issues are.